# Corydra with injured barbels stopped eating?

Tags: health, fish, diet

My mum bought 2 small (baby) juli eye corydra a from a pet shop on Monday. On Friday when I came to hers for the weekend, I noticed that one of them was missing like 2 whole barbels and it looks a little white (not cottony) and a little swollen (just a bit).

My mum said he's been eating but I don't think he has as he isn't eating at all now and his sides are on the skinny side. Not sure what to do, never had this before.

Comment: A picture would help.

Answer (score 2):

Aquarium fish can go a few days without food. Overfeeding tends to be a bigger problem anyway.

But, without barbels Corydoras will have a hard time eating. You should always have a soft underground where Cordydoras cannot hurt their barbels. For if they lose their barbels they will have a very hard time finding food and will very likely starve.

*Without a picture it's hard to tell what is going on. Only time will tell if they are hurt.